# Infinite shake animation for a UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get a UIImageView to shake indefinitely.

```
        var coffeeImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "coffee.png"))
        coffeeImageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, self.view.frame.size.height - 100, 50, 50)
        self.view.addSubview(coffeeImageView)

        let coffeeShakeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        coffeeShakeAnimation.duration = 0.07
        coffeeShakeAnimation.repeatCount = 20
        coffeeShakeAnimation.autoreverses = true
        coffeeShakeAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(coffeeImageView.center.x - 10, coffeeImageView.center.y))
        coffeeShakeAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(coffeeImageView.center.x + 10, coffeeImageView.center.y))
        coffeeImageView.layer.addAnimation(coffeeShakeAnimation, forKey: "position")
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
let coffeeShakeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
```

by

```
let coffeeShakeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
```

it will shake